Should we remove answers to self-help questions?
Sometimes, an answer will be posted to a self-help question before it is closed. For example, this recent question got an answer (https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/why-people-get-mad-when-you-tell-them-they-did-you-bad) but was closed shortly thereafter. 
I'm wondering if the answers to such questions, when they are attempting to offer diagnoses or treatment, should be deleted.

My rule of thumb is to downvote, and only worry about deleting if it is something serious like a suggestion for medication, spam, or outright offensive. However, if you feel an answer should be deleted then I think you can vote for deleting and if enough users agree, the answer will be deleted.
